# Fetching twitter public feeds as JSON

Tags: ios, json, twitter

As a part of my project I need to show the list of tweets in iOS app. I tried with the below code but its returning the JSON. The same code is works fine with version 1. Now the twitter api version is 1.1 and one another warning I got that `TWRequest is deprecated`. This deprecation is not the issue of this even I got same thing with `SLRequest`. Here my problem is I need to fetch the JSON of Particular user tweets without authentication or with authentication

```
TWRequest *postequest=[[TWRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.0/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=coolCracker&count=2"] parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

    [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
            NSString *output;
            if ([urlResponse statusCode]==200) {
              NSError *err;
              NSDictionary *PublicTimeline=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&err];
              output=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %li\nPublic timeline:\n%@",(long)[urlResponse statusCode],PublicTimeline];
            }
            else
            {
              output=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No feed HTTP response was: %li\n",(long)[urlResponse statusCode]];

            }
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayResults:) withObject:output waitUntilDone:NO];
          }];

-(void)displayResults:(NSString *)text
{
  NSLog(@"tweets feed %@",text);
}
```

Comment: You cannot. The new Twitter API **requires** authentication.

Comment: `SLRequest` should work if you're signed in to Twitter via the iOS settings app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this in my work and it worked pretty well. Use STTwitter. Download STTwitter files [here.](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter)

Place this in your view didload:

```
  STTwitterAPI *twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIAppOnlyWithConsumerKey:@"your consumer key"
                                                        consumerSecret:@"your secret key"];

[twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *bearerToken) {

    [twitter getUserTimelineWithScreenName:@"your twitter account name"
                              successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses) {

                                  self.twitterFeedList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:statuses];

                                  [self->listView reloadData];

                              } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

                                  NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);

                              }];

} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);

}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Below code is working for me. Though TWRequest is deprecated it works for now. Later you can change it to SLRequest.

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *twitterType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    // Request access from the user to use their Twitter accounts.
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted == YES){
            //get accounts to use.
            NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:twitterType];
            if ([accounts count] > 0) {
                NSLog(@"account: %@", accounts);
                ACAccount *loggedinaccount;
                loggedinaccount = accounts[0];
                // get tweets

                TWRequest *postRequest=[[TWRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=HuntEthane&count=2"] parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
                [postRequest setAccount:loggedinaccount];
                [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                    NSString *output;
                    if ([urlResponse statusCode]==200) {
                        NSError *err;
                        NSDictionary *PublicTimeline=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&err];
                        output=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %li\nPublic timeline:\n%@",(long)[urlResponse statusCode],PublicTimeline];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        output=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No feed HTTP response was: %li\n",(long)[urlResponse statusCode]];

                    }
                    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayResults:) withObject:output waitUntilDone:NO];
                }];


            }


        }else{
            // show alert to inser user_name and password to login on twitter
            UIAlertView *alertTwitterAccount = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Enter with your twitter account"
                                   message:nil
                                   delegate:self
                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                   otherButtonTitles:@"Login", nil];
            [alertTwitterAccount setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
            [[alertTwitterAccount textFieldAtIndex:0] setPlaceholder:@"User"];
            [alertTwitterAccount setDelegate:self];
            [alertTwitterAccount setTag:1];
            [alertTwitterAccount show];
        }
    }];
```

Remember to add below frameworks to make this code work.

- Twitter.FrameWork
- Social.FrameWork
- Accounts.Framework
- Security.FrameWork

  If you want to use `SLRequest` instead of `TWRequest`, replace request statement with below statement

  `SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest
                                        requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                        URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=HuntEthane&count=2"]parameters:nil];`

Comment: do u know how to find the slug or list id, i am really struggling to find the slug or list id of twitter list

Comment: use this url --- https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/statuses.json?slug=teams&owner_screen_name=HuntEthane&count=1

Comment: For more on twitter API endpoints refer link --- https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

Comment: did you used those, i've gone through this already but no where i found how to get list_id or slug of a list

Comment: @Coolcracker No I haven' tried for list_id or slug of list

Answer (score -2):

Moving forward the easiest way is adoption of **Fabric.io** from Tweeter as the development platform includes **Tweeter embeds**: https://get.fabric.io/native-social

*"The easiest way to bring Twitter content into your app."*

Honestly, I did not look into authentication part needed for Fabric.io.

Otherwise you need to follow and respect rules for accessing Twitter *REST APIs* or *Streaming APIs*, both well documented. *OAuth* authentication is required.

If you wish to avoid authentication in your app you can write a simple web REST API that will take care of authentication and serve (selected) tweets to your iOS app.

1. First, you’ll need to register an app with Twitter
2. Write down your *Consumer Key* and *Consumer Secret*
3. Write a simple server API (proxy) in your language of choice.

> I personally prefer *JavaScript* on *Node.js*. Consider using  libraries like *express.js* and *oauth* available on *npm*, but you can search npm for any other implemented Twitter proxy/API.
>   The code essentially consists of getting an OAuth Access token and then calling selected twitter APIs, and respecting ratelimits by caching results.